# How to delete the sheets after a certain sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have worksheet in my workbook as **Test**. There are other worksheets as well. I want to delete the worksheets that appear on the right of the worksheet called Test.

How do I do that in VBA? Need some help on this.

Edit:

```
Set test= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
For i = Sheets.Count To (test.Index + 1) Step -1
    Delete Sheets(i)
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  The sheet Test will have an `Index` property indicating its tab position - you can use that.

Comment: Not sure how to start. Tried searching. not much of a help.

Comment: Use  `For i = Sheets.Count To (shtTest.Index+1) Step-1`  where `shtTest` is a variable representing the worksheet "Test".  Delete `Sheets(i)` on each iteration.

Comment: There is a compile error at Delete saying sub or function not defined

Comment: Update your question with your code - difficult to debug when invisible.

Comment: Record a macro where you delete a sheet. That will give you the code.

Comment: @lakesh yes, and recording a macro will give you `vba` code. Go to the 'developer' tab on the ribbon and select 'Record Macro'. Then delete a sheet. Then press 'stop recording', go into the VBA editor and your code will be there in a new module.

Comment: How to avoid the pop up box saying " Data may exist in the sheet(s) selected for deletion. To permanently delete the data, press Delete". How to avoid this.

Comment: FYI - Google has ready answers for all of these "how to" questions - please try there *first*.

Comment: @TimWilliams please add yours an answer. Will mark it right.

Comment: @garysstudent's answer is fine - you should flag that as the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = "Test" Then
            j = i
        End If
    Next i

    If j = 0 Or j = Sheets.Count Then Exit Sub

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = Sheets.Count To j + 1 Step -1
            Sheets(i).Delete
        Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking an alternate approach to what has already been offered, if you had 10 sheets (worksheets..?) and wanted to remove everything after the **Test** worksheet, simply continually delete `sheet(Sheets("test").Index + 1)` until sheets.count is less than Sheets("test").Index +1.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'take off the training wheels
Do While Sheets.Count > Sheets("test").Index
    Sheets(Sheets("test").Index + 1).Delete
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```